# The pattern of possible numbers of non-congruent triangles for different size dot grids.

Tags: triangles

If I have four dots, arranged in two rows of two to make a square, and I draw a triangle by joining three of the dots, there are four triangles I can draw, but they are all the same shape (they are congruent).
If I start with nine dots, arranged in three rows of three to make a square, how many different (non-congruent) triangles is it possible to draw?
What if I start with a square formed of sixteen dots?
Can you generalise for n2 dots?

Comment: Do the triangles have to be made of as many dots as n+1

Comment: Start with a simpler problem that you cannot yet solve: How many nondegenerate triangles are there  in a grid of $n^2$ points?

Comment: Can the triangles be turned in space? Or only in the plane? I.e., do you distinguish them according to chirality?

Comment: The triangles you count for each number of dots can not be rotations of reflection of each other.